# Frame Navigation UWP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hey I want to make something like a slide show, where you start the application and it goes through pages but the program don't load.

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        while (true)
        {
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(werbungPage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(ChartZielPage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(mitarbeiteronlinePage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MomentaneKundenPage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(OutlookKalenderPage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(ChartServerPage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(ChartWheaterPage));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hey I want to make something like a slide show, where you start the application and it goes through pages but the program don't load.

The problem is `Thread.Sleep` make UI-thread deadlock, for your requirement, we suggest use [`DispathcerTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-18362) to process the slide navigation.

```
private int index;
private List<Type> pages = new List<Type>() { typeof(TestPage), typeof(BlankPage), typeof(BlankPage) };
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (index == pages.Count)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    this.contentFrame.Navigate(pages[index]);
    index++;    
}
```